# Solving the equation $8\Delta = \left( {b + c} \right)\left( {bc + 1} \right)$

Tags: trigonometry

In  $\Delta ABC$, $8\Delta  = \left( {b + c} \right)\left( {bc + 1} \right)$ then circumradius of   is $\Delta ABC$ is     ( where $\Delta$  denotes area of triangle and b, c are length of sides AC and AB respectively)

(1)  $\sqrt \Delta  $

(2)  $\frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\Delta } }}$

(3)  $\sqrt {2\Delta } $

(4)  $\frac{1}{{\sqrt \Delta  }}$

My approach is as follow $R = \frac{{abc}}{{4\Delta }}$ where R is the circumradius of the $\Delta ABC$

$\Delta  = \frac{1}{2}bc\sin A$,

$8\Delta  = 4bc\sin A = \left( {b + c} \right)\left( {bc + 1} \right) \Rightarrow 4bc\sin A - bc\left( {b + c} \right) = \left( {b + c} \right)$

Nor able to proceed further.

Comment: Try the obvious example $b=c=\sin A=1$.

Comment: @user10354138
 yes this is what is mentioned but how did we arrive to this conclusion  that is important

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting everything in terms of $R$ and sine of the angles, the condition $8\Delta=(b+c)(bc+1)$ gives
$$
4R^2\sin B\sin C-8R\frac{\sin A\sin B\sin C}{\sin B+\sin C}+1=0.
$$
As this quadratic in $R$ must have a positive root, we get
$$
\left(\frac{2\sin A\sin B\sin C}{\sin B+\sin C}\right)^2-\sin B\sin C\geq 0.
$$
That is,
$$
4\sin^2A\sin B\sin C\geq (\sin B+\sin C)^2
$$
Can you finish it from here?

> ! Apply AM-GM to $(\sin B+\sin C)^2$ and we have $$
> 4\sin^2A\sin B\sin C\geq 4\sin B\sin C\geq 4\sin^2A\sin B\sin C
> $$

Answer (score 0):

We have from the equation $4\sin A = \left(\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c} \right)(bc+1)$

$\Rightarrow 4 \sin A \ge \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{bc}} \times 2 \sqrt{bc} = 4$

Hence $\sin A =1 =b =c$